How to understand the non-linear calculation model of demagnetization curve correctly?
in the doc of MotorCAD, I found that the demagnetization curve can be calculated by like this non linear model:

In above formula, the Br at specific temperature can be calculated like this:

And the k2 can be calculated like this:

In above formula, the Hcj at specific temperature can be calculated like this:

After plugining in these conformed corrected values:
Tref = 25
Br(Tref) = 3
Hcj(Tref) = 7.2e05

α = -0.15
β = -0.4
k1 = 6e-05

u0 = 4 * math.pi * 1e-07
ur = 3.316
E = 1
e = 2.7182

H = 25

into first formula,I got a very small negative B:
-8.378658730192973e+227
since the B values in the second quadrant of a demagnetization curve should be all great than 0, I got a wrong calculation result.
I may misunderstand the formula,can anybody help to explain the first formula or give a link to original source of this formula?

Actually, $-8\times10^{227}$ is a very large negative number. Where do any of the numeric values you have come from?

The problem is solved by adding a negative sign before $k_2$ in the first formula.
